# Where do classes get their default '__dict__' attributes from?

Tags: python, class

If we compare the lists generated by applying the `dir()` built-in to the object superclass and to a 'dummy', bodyless class, such as

```
class A():
    pass
```

we find that the A class has three attributes `('__dict__', '__module__' and '__weakref__')` that are not present in the object class.

Where does the A class inherit these additional attributes from?

Comment: From the parent of all, `object`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- The `__dict__` attribute is created by the internal code in `type.__new__`.  The class's metaclass may influence the eventual content of `__dict__`. If you are using `__slots__`, you will have no `__dict__` attribute.
- `__module__` is set when the class is compiled, so the instance inherits this attribute from the class. You can verify this by performing the test `inst.__module__ is cls.__module__` (given that `inst` is an instance of `cls`), and also by modifying `cls.__module__` and observing that `inst.__module__` reflects this change.

  (you can also do stupid things like setting `inst.__module__` to a differing value from `cls.__module__`. Not sure why this isn't a readonly attribute.)
- `__weakref__` is created when the instance is; AFAIK it's completely controlled by the internal CPython object-creation system. This attribute is only present on instances of `object` subclasses -- for example instances of `int`, `list`, `set`, `tuple` have no `__weakref__` attribute.

  In interpreting this explanation, keep in mind that `class C:` is equivalent to `class C(object):` for Python3. For Python2, plain `class C:` will generate instances without  `__weakref__` (or a number of other attributes acquired from the `object` implementation).

Comment: `__dict__` is set by `type.__new__`. The value returned by the metaclass' `__prepare__` method is *passed* to the metaclass' `__new__` method (which almost always eventually is passed to `type.__new__` if a new class is actually being created). And `type.__new__` complains if you give it anything other than an actual dict. So whatever `__prepare__` returns has no influence on what the actual `__dict__` attribute is, it's just used to accumulate the *contents* that will eventually be added to `__dict__`. Python2 is the same, but you don't get to choose the accumulating collection.

Comment: @Ben : Thanks, I've clarified that

Comment: "In interpreting this explanation, keep in mind that `class C:` is equivalent to `class C(object):`" - only true for Py3, not for Py2.